# What does [1] mean in this code?

Tags: python

I have just started to learn python. I got this statement:

```
output= " name: abc" 
log =output.split("=")[1]
```

What does the `[1]` denote? Why is it used?

Comment: List indexing. It gets *second* item from list yielded by `split`, which in this case would not exist.

Answer (score 6):

The `[1]` is indexing into the list returned by `output.split("=")`; if that method returns a list of 2 or more elements, the `[1]` indexes the second element.

In your specific case, it'll raise an `IndexError`, as there is no `=` in `output`. Because of this, the `output.split("=")` method returns just a list with just **one** string.

You can try things like these in a Python interpreter prompt:

```
>>> output= " name: abc" 
>>> output.split('=')
[' name: abc']
>>> output.split('=')[0]
' name: abc'
>>> output.split('=')[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Had you split on `:` instead you'd have gotten a more useful result:

```
>>> output.split(':')[1]
' abc'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what the statement means:

```
output= " name: abc"

log =output.split("=")[1]
```

Take the string `output` and split it on `'='` and then get the second element in the resulting list (index 1)

However, you can see that your `output` doesn't really contain any `=`, you probably want:

```
output= "name=abc"
```

Here is the breakdown:

```
a = output.split('=')
>>> a
['name', 'abc']

>>> a[1]
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

this is useful when you know for sure the string has the (=) equal-to symbol or the any character that you are splitting with. so that it splits the string and returns the list.

and then from the list you can choose which part of string is useful for you

in your case it will return IndexError since it is not returning a list.

```
output= " name= abc"
log =output.split("=")[1]
```

in this case this will be useful